# Use BOOL as property of button

Tags: objective-c, macos, object, boolean

I have a boolean that I would like to set as a property of a button:

```cs
int tag = (int)[sender tag];
NSString* keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addButton%d.hidden", tag];
[self setValue:YES forKey:keyPath];
```

I can't do this directly as the addButton's number changes according to the sender's tag.

I've already tried with:

```
setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```

but doesn't work.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole problem is based on bad architecture. Having properties `addButton1`, `addButton2`, `addButton3` etc. is hard to work with in the first place. Every time you see yourself adding numbers at the end of your properties, use an array instead.

```
NSArray *addButtons = @[self.addButton1, self.addButton2, self.addButton3];
```

and then simply

```
[addButtons[sender.tag - 1] setHidden:YES];
```

Using KVC is good only for specific situations. If you are a beginner, try to not use it. It's a bad habit to overuse it. Access properties directly, not using string names.

Comment: Thanks, worked! Just one thing: I used  [addButtons[[sender tag]]...] to make it work, otherwise it gave me an error.

Comment: @MatteoLaMendola It depends whether your buttons start at `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably `setValue:forKeyPath:`, the value must be an object

```
[self setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:keyPath];
```